# Python3 - Failed to load library on "import cairosvg"

Tags: python-3.x, module, python-module, cairo, python-3.7

I'm trying to install CairoSVG for Python 3. I ran `pip3 install cairosvg` without any errors, but when I try to import the module via `import cairosvg`, I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#5>", line 1, in <module>
    import cairosvg
  File "D:\Programs\Python3\lib\site-packages\cairosvg\__init__.py", line 41, in <module>
    from . import surface  # noqa
  File "D:\Programs\Python3\lib\site-packages\cairosvg\surface.py", line 24, in <module>
    import cairocffi as cairo
  File "D:\Programs\Python3\lib\site-packages\cairocffi\__init__.py", line 41, in <module>
    cairo = dlopen(ffi, 'cairo', 'cairo-2', 'cairo-gobject-2')
  File "D:\Programs\Python3\lib\site-packages\cairocffi\__init__.py", line 38, in dlopen
    raise OSError("dlopen() failed to load a library: %s" % ' / '.join(names))
OSError: dlopen() failed to load a library: cairo / cairo-2 / cairo-gobject-2
```

Answer (score 2):

`cairosvg` python package doesn't install `cairo` library on your computer. You need to download an installer and make sure it's accessable by python. Also you need to be aware if python is built for the same instruction set as `cairo` library (e.g. x32 — x32 and x86_64 — x86_64). Python can't use libraries built for other architecture.